# Getting all list items of an unordered list in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have these tag cloud list

```
<ul #id = "tag-cloud-list">
    <li class = "items">Music</li>
    <li class = "items">Lion</li>
    <li class = "items">Dwarf</li<
</ul>
```

That was generated by  JQuery. The items here are tags that I will insert to the database. Now my question is it possible to get all `<li>` items inside the ul? and put them inside a PHP array? because each of these tags will be inserted in the database. if there's no way I can get a li items using php then how would Insert these list items into the database? because I needed them since it is tag to a certain item or post

Comment: Additionally to creating the list elements with jQuery, you can send the item contents as an AJAX request to PHP.

Comment: How would I do that? any sites or places where I can see a tutorial about that?

Comment: you can ajax them on creation, or use form to post them after the creation. not sure what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kasia gogolek I am trying to accomplish the second one you mentioned

Comment: From what have the 3 items been generated from then?

Comment: You can append a hidden input with each `<li>` item and then use a `form` to put the values in the hidden inputs into database. Of course this would mean putting a 'submit' or 'insert' button in HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make an AJAX call:

```
var lis = new Array();

// Iterate through the <li> items
$("#tag-cloud-list").children("li").each(function()
{
    lis.push($(this).text());
});

// Make AJAX call and set data to something like "Music::Lion::Dwarf"
$.ajax({
    url: "dostuff.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { items: lis.join("::") },
    success: function() { alert("OK"); }
});
```

Then in the PHP script, use

```
$lis = $_POST['items'];
$liarray = explode("::", $lis);
```

to retrieve an array of the `li` items

Comment: inside the dostuff.php will I automatically see the list items?

Comment: @KyelJmD In `dostuff.php`, you first need to capture the `data` and then run an INSERT query with those variables

Comment: soo basically you declared "items" in the parameter data then it is automatically inserted  in hte $_POST global array?

Comment: That's correct, the name you give it in the `data` parameter (doesn't need to have any quotes or declaration) automatically becomes a `POST` item. So if you like you could name it foo, or anything: `data: { foo:lis.join("::") },`. Then you'd have to call `$lis = $_POST['foo'];`

Comment: Wow AJAX Magic! but just a question what does lis.join("::") do? and in the explode(). why did you use ("::") ?

Comment: `lis.join("::")` makes the array into a single string, concatenated with `::` in between, so an array of `array("Music", "Lion", "Dwarf")` will become a single string containing `"Music::Lion::Dwarf"`

Comment: You could also change it to another character, but think about it when you need to explode it and the names contain the same character. So when you join with say `. (period)`, and one of the items' name contains a `.`, you could get confusing results when exploding on `.`.. I.e. `array("Mus.ic", "Li.on", "Dwa.rf")` will become `"Mus.ic.Li.on.Dwa.rf"`, then on explode, the array has `Mus, ic, Li, on, Dwa, rf`

Comment: @GeenHenk I posted a question that is related to this do you mind if you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769647/ajax-call-with-post-in-php#comment15629983_11769647 I've used your code as a guideline for that

Answer (score 3):

You can't get these in PHP unless you send the data back to the server somehow. PHP executes on the server, if this is coming in via a jquery, then PHP knows nothing about it.

You will need to either use javascript to get all the information and send it back to the server, or you need to send the entire page HTML (somehow) back to the server to be looked at by PHP. I suggest the first option.

Edit: I am not flash-hot with javascript, just use some basic functions, but you could write an event into a `<div>` or where the data is coming into along. The function would find how many `<li>` there are in the `<ul id="tag-cloud-list">` pop them into an array and send them to the PHP server, by a form or ajax query.

Sorry that I can't help much with the js code.

Comment: @KyelJmD: try some pure JS and get the innerHTML, don't rely on jQuery much

Comment: @PaulDinh A little curious here. May I know the reason why jQuery isn't reliable?

Comment: @asprin: i didn't say jQuery is not reliable, i said "don't rely on it"

Comment: @PaulDinh My mistake. What I wanted to ask was why prefer pure JS over jQuery?

Comment: @PaulDinh interesting comment - KyelJmD has made the decision to use jQuery, so why use pure js? jQuery is meant to make things easier. GeenHenks answer shows this perfectly. Not a rant just a thought...

Comment: @asprin, uhm, what if jQuery is no longer in development? standard js still stands.

Comment: It's **really** worth it to learn jQuery, it's so easy to work with once you know it

Comment: Completely agree with @GreenHenk. The moment I grasped the concept of  jQuery, I hate the thought of going back to pure JS. jQuery makes life so much simpler

Comment: Honestly speaking. I haven't had idea exercises on AJAX but indeed the JQuery has helped me a lot you can easily understand it. but then again it wouldn't hurt if you know Pure JS. but that being said JQuery makes life so much easier.

Comment: @PaulDinh a truly awesome comment "what if jQuery is no longer in development", I'm putting my computer in the bin as we spk :)

Comment: @PaulDinh - its madness to say "don't rely on jQuery". It solves an **unbelievable** amount of problems that would otherwise make serious JavaScript development take forever. jQuery should be embraced as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all items in the ul using .find() function from JQuery and make a POST with ajax and process the information