# Ajax Call with Post in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery Tagit Demo Page (HTML)</title>
  <script src="demo/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="demo/js/jquery-ui.1.8.20.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tagit.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tagit-stylish-yellow.css">

  <script>


    $(document).ready(function () {


    var list = new Array();
    var availableTags = [];

     $('#demo2').tagit({tagSource:availableTags});


     $('#demo2GetTags').click(function () {
        showTags($('#demo2').tagit('tags'))
      });

     /*
    $('li[data-value]').each(function(){
        alert($(this).data("value"));
    });*/

    $('#demo2').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "demo3.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { items:list.join("::") },
            success: alert("OK")
        });
    });

    function showTags(tags) {


        console.log(tags);
        var string = "";
        for (var i in tags){
          string += tags[i].value+" ";
         }
          var list = string.split(" ");
          //The last element of the array contains " "
          list.pop();   
        }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <?php 

        $lis = $_POST['items'];
        $liarray = explode("::", $lis);
        print_r($liarray);

    ?>
<div class="box">
  <div class="note">
    You can manually specify tags in your markup by adding <em>list items</em> to the unordered list!
  </div>

    <ul id="demo2" data-name="demo2">
        <li data-value="here">here</li>
        <li data-value="are">are</li>
        <li data-value="some...">some</li>
        <!-- notice that this tag is setting a different value :) -->
        <li data-value="initial">initial</li>
        <li data-value="tags">tags</li>
    </ul>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="demo2GetTags" value="Get Tags">Get Tags</button>
    <button id="demo2ResetTags" value="Reset Tags">Reset Tags</button>
    <button id="view-tags">View Tags on the console </button>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will just transfer the list of items in the dostuff.php but when I try to print_r it on PHP nothing won't come out. why is that?

I am doing an ajax request on this line

```
$('#demo2').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "demo3.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { items:list.join("::") },
                success: alert("OK")
            });
        });
```

and the code in PHP

```
<?php 

        $lis = $_POST['items'];
        $liarray = explode("::", $lis);
        print_r($liarray);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, given the limited information, but it would appear that you're expecting *something* to happen with the data sent back from the server.. but you literally do nothing with it.  On success, you have it display an alert... and nothing else.

Try changing your success entry to the following:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#wrap").html(data);
}
```

This will fill the div with the data from the `POST` request.  The reason it shows up as nothing as it is..., you aren't loading the currently executing page with the data needed for the `print_r` to actually echo anything.

**Edit**: How to insert values into database;

Database interaction now-a-days is done with either custom wrappers, or the [`php Data Object`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), also referred to as PDO, as opposed to the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

First, you prepare your database object, similar to how a connection is done in the aforementioned deprecated functions:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=database", $username, $password);
```

Then, you can begin interaction, preparing a query statement..

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET column1 = :column1 WHERE id = :id");
```

Binding a parameter in said statement..

```
$stmt->bindParam(':column1', $column1);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

And finally executing the query:

```
try {
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

PDO auto-escapes any strings bound in the prior statements, making it save from SQL-injection attacks, and it speeds up the process of multiple executions.  Take the following example:

```
foreach ($_POST as $id) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Since the id parameter is already bound to `$id`, all you have to do is change `$id` and execute the query.

Comment: but what if I want those list of items to be inserted in the DB?

Comment: @KyelJmD Then on your php page, you process the values with your database interaction code.  Let me give you an example using PDO.

Comment: Soo with that the list of items will be inserted to the DB? I am kinda confused. where did the $_POST['items'] go? I thought that this     data: { items:list.join("::") }, will add items in the super global $_POST

Comment: @KyelJmD It was an example.  It was not meant to be something you just straight-up and copy, but extrapolate from.

Comment: I am still confused but I'll try my best to understand your answer. all I wanted was to print out the list of items using PHP and then insert those to DB. but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Where where you expecting the PHP result of `print_r` to "come out"?

Try changing your AJAX call to this (only the value of `success` is different):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo3.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { items:list.join("::") },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

With this, the output of your PHP template, which you would normally see if you posted to it the old fashioned way (ie. with a form and a full page reload), will display in an alert.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Try putting the PHP code to be accessed via AJAX in a different PHP file instead of the same one.

Comment: it returned me an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add encodeURI for the jQuery part,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "demo3.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { items: encodeURIComponent (list.join("::")) },
  success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
  }
});
```

And urldecode for the PHP part:

```
$lis = $_POST['items'];
$liarray = explode("::", urldecode($lis));
print_r($liarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

*3 things*:

Set your AJAX's `success` to show the echos/prints given in your PHP script

```
success: function(result)
{
    $("#somecontainer").html(result);
}
```

That way ANYTHING that gets printed in a PHP script otherwise, will be put in i.e.

```
<div id="somecontainer">
    Result of PHPcode here
</div>
```

---

Second, instead of

```
var string = "";
for (var i in tags)
{
    string += tags[i].value+" ";
}

var list = string.split(" ");
//The last element of the array contains " "
list.pop();
```

use [`push()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_push.htm). This adds the value at the next unoccupied index in the array:

```
var string = "";
for (var i in tags)
{
    list.push(tags[i].value);
}
```

That way you don't have to pop the last element off.

---

Third point: put your PHP code in a separate file (and your JavaScript/jQuery as well). Have like:

```
/root/index.html
/root/script/dostuff.php
/root/script/myscript.js
```

then let your AJAX call to `url: "/script/dostuff.php"`