# Sending array via Ajax fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var labels = new Array();

<?php foreach($crud_data as $cd ) { ?>
  labels['<?php echo $cd['name'] ; ?>'] = '<?php echo $cd['label'] ; ?>';
<?php } ?>

$.post('url.php' , { labels:labels} );
```

Why can I not send `labels` array like this? It doesn't show anything in Firebug.

My `console.log(labels)` result:

```
[]

avatar
"avatar"

email
"email"

id
"id"

name
"name"

password
"password"
```

if i populate array like this

```
<?php foreach($crud_data as $cd ) { ?>
  labels.push('<?php echo $cd['label'] ; ?>');
<?php } ?>

$.post('url.php' , { labels:labels} );
```

it works fine !

Comment: hi max, can you `console.log(labels)` before post?

Comment: @demo sorry , i've edited my question

Comment: How do you know the request fails? Please provide more information.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11757692/1062281

Comment: @FelixKling request doens't fail ! it just doesn't send the `labels` ! check out my edit

Comment: what does your php endpoint expect? cause in the second case you're sending an array and in the first one an object.

Comment: @soulcheck it expects an array , but i don't think this matters cuz ajax request doesnt send it in the first place .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I see now. If you have string keys, you have to use an object, not an array:

```
var labels = {};
```

Arrays in JavaScript are supposed to only hold elements with numeric keys. While you can assign arbitrary properties to arrays, they are not considered to be elements of the array and thus ignored by most processes which deal with arrays.

Additionally you might want to have a look at [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to see how jQuery will convert the input to a transport-able string and adjust your data structure accordingly.

Comment: I was about to write that.

Comment: thnak you , javascript is like an important clown !

Answer (score 1):

```
labels['<?php echo $cd['name'] ; ?>'] =
```

It seems you want to create an associative array, which is in fact an object in JavaScript (JavaScript has no dedicated associative arrays). So the array itself is in fact empty because you are adding properties to the array object.